# JSP Error- illegal to have multiple occurrences of 'contentType' with different values

Tags: jsp, glassfish-3, jsp-tags

I am working on the Netbeans Affable tutorial on this [page](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/manage-sessions.html#time-out) using the Netbeans 7 IDE , Glassfish 3+ server , the servlet class and session beans. The servlet class is expected to invoke the index.jsp class.

But anytime I run the project in Netbeans I get an error.

this is the index.jsp page.

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql"%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/affablebean.css">
    <title>The Affable Bean</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="indexLeftColumn">
                <div id="welcomeText">
                    <p style="font-size: larger">Welcome to the online home of the Affable Bean Green Grocer.</p>

                    <p>Enjoy browsing and learning more about our unique home delivery
                        service bringing you fresh organic produce, dairy, meats, breads
                        and other delicious and healthy items to your doorstep.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="indexRightColumn">
                <c:forEach var="category" items="${categories}">
                    <div class="categoryBox">
                        <a href="category?${category.id}">
                            <span class="categoryLabel"></span>
                            <span class="categoryLabelText">${category.name}</span>

                            <img src="${initParam.categoryImagePath}${category.name}.jpg"
                                 alt="${category.name}" class="categoryImage">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </c:forEach>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

hi is the error message from the glassfish 3+ server

```
WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /index.jsp(9,0) PWC5988: Page directive: illegal to have multiple occurrences of 'contentType' with different values (old: text/html; charset=UTF-8, new: text/html)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:81)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:376)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:204)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$DirectiveVisitor.visit(Validator.java:173)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$PageDirective.accept(Node.java:600)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2297)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2347)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2353)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:499)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2297)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validate(Validator.java:1826)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:223)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:451)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:625)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:375)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /index.jsp(9,0) PWC5988: Page directive: illegal to have multiple occurrences of 'contentType' with different values (old: text/html; charset=UTF-8, new: text/html)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:81)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:376)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:204)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$DirectiveVisitor.visit(Validator.java:173)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$PageDirective.accept(Node.java:600)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2297)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2347)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2353)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:499)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2297)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validate(Validator.java:1826)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:223)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:451)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:625)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:375)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /index.jsp(9,0) PWC5988: Page directive: illegal to have multiple occurrences of 'contentType' with different values (old: text/html; charset=UTF-8, new: text/html)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:81)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:376)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:204)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$DirectiveVisitor.visit(Validator.java:173)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$PageDirective.accept(Node.java:600)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2297)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2347)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2353)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:499)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2297)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validate(Validator.java:1826)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:223)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:451)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:625)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:375)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: You've written `contentType` attribute twice.

Comment: that is what the error is saying but I am not able to trace  were the content type appears twice. Am new to JSP can any one help

Answer (score 2):

The content header type looks to be set in both:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

and

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

the exception is fired because the charset is missing in the page directive. 
That's why it seems to be considered as a different contentType.